# How to avoid the default Page behaviour of jumping on to the TOP when any overlay appears?

Tags: jquery, layout, html, render

I have a clickable button on the bottom. As soon as I click on the button, it opens an overlay but the page jumps to TOP.(I mean to say, Page goes to top- the same way as when it loads). I want to avoid this behaviour and page should be centered at the bottom only rather than jumping to the TOP when my overlay div appears.

My Code is

```
onclick="showOverLay();"

function showOverLay()
{
 $('.overlayBarcode').fadeIn('normal');
 return false;
}


div.overlayBarcode {
    background: url("/DiscoverCenter/images/white.png") no-repeat ;
    _background: url("/DiscoverCenter/images/white.png") no-repeat ;
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding:  40px;
    width: 576px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Please let me know, how to solve this problem.I am trying this since a long.

Thanks

Comment: Is your button a button with type `submit` by chance?

Comment: If you're using a link make sure it doesn't have # as the URL

Comment: Can you post some of the html?

Comment: @Nick, It is a whole HTML and it s a company data so,i am affraid I can not put it.But it is a default behaviour of a page to load on the top, so how to prevent that is something i dont know :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a link? With a hash mark for the href? If so, that's the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent default in your click function

This is just an example function

```
$('a.some_class').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var some_example = document.getElementById('artist_one').offsetHeight;
    $('#some_id').css("height", container_height );
});
```

Comment: This is very old thread but thanks for your reply. This would help others.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just grab and then restore the scroll?

```
var showOverLay = function(){
    var curScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.overlayBarcode').fadeIn('normal', function(){
        $(window).scrollTop(curScoll);
    });

    return false;
};
```

or

```
var showOverLay = function(){
    var curScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.overlayBarcode').fadeIn('normal');
    $(window).scrollTop(curScoll);

    return false;
};
```

Comment: One Question here, If I want to restore the window positioning as per the overlay opening position, can i do it some way?

Comment: "as per the overlay opening position"?

Comment: I'm not understanding. You mean how can you restore back to the scroll position that the fadeIn() on '$('.overlayBarcode')' takes it to?

Comment: Yes, I need to restore the window position to the overlay opening position, Currently I am giving it absolute height and width from top,but I need to restore the window as per the current cursor position.

Comment: The first code example should work then, unless you mean you want the window scroll to come to the top of the mouse pointer.

Comment: I used function showOverLay()
{
   var curScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('.overlayBarcode').fadeIn('normal');
       $(window).scrollTop(curScoll);
       return false;
    } and in JSP i used <div class="overlayBarcode" id="external2">, but it shows curScroll not defined, Whats wrong here, sir

Comment: Change it to '$("body").scrollTop();'